# SSL certificate Error with App Transport Security

Tags: ios, cordova, ssl-certificate, xcode7.2

I have created Hybrid Mobile app with the support of cordova.

In this project I trying to access https server, which has SSL certificate for security.

On emulate the app I am getting following two errors on Xcode7.2.

```
CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
```

I tried following keys in info.plist not working.

[image]

How to access https from hybrid mobile app using cordova?

I run `nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose https://XXX.XXXX.XXX` anf got following result,

```
Starting ATS Diagnostics

Configuring ATS Info.plist keys and displaying the result of HTTPS loads to https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx.
A test will "PASS" if URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError: returns a nil error.
================================================================================

Default ATS Secure Connection
---
ATS Default Connection
ATS Dictionary:
{
}
2017-03-20 19:27:19.190 nscurl[16582:163070] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2017-03-20 19:27:19.191 nscurl[16582:163070] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
Result : FAIL
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbdf341b6f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9824, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
---

================================================================================

Allowing Arbitrary Loads

---
Allow All Loads
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSAllowsArbitraryLoads = true;
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring TLS exceptions for xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx

---
TLSv1.2
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.2";
        };
    };
}
2017-03-20 19:27:19.612 nscurl[16582:163070] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2017-03-20 19:27:19.612 nscurl[16582:163070] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
Result : FAIL
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbdf360c3c0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9824, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
---

---
TLSv1.1
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.1";
        };
    };
}
2017-03-20 19:27:19.669 nscurl[16582:163070] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2017-03-20 19:27:19.669 nscurl[16582:163070] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
Result : FAIL
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbdf3727cf0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9824, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
---

---
TLSv1.0
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.0";
        };
    };
}
2017-03-20 19:27:19.725 nscurl[16582:163070] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824)
2017-03-20 19:27:19.726 nscurl[16582:163070] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
Result : FAIL
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbdf371abe0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9824, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9824}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
---

================================================================================

Configuring PFS exceptions for xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx

---
Disabling Perfect Forward Secrecy
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx" =         {
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
2017-03-20 19:27:19.784 nscurl[16582:163070] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)
2017-03-20 19:27:19.785 nscurl[16582:163070] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)
Result : FAIL
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbdf354f3d0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9801, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
---

================================================================================

Configuring PFS exceptions and allowing insecure HTTP for xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx

---
Disabling Perfect Forward Secrecy and Allowing Insecure HTTP
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
2017-03-20 19:27:19.843 nscurl[16582:163070] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)
2017-03-20 19:27:19.908 nscurl[16582:163070] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)
2017-03-20 19:27:19.962 nscurl[16582:163070] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)
2017-03-20 19:27:19.962 nscurl[16582:163070] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)
Result : FAIL
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbdf3488c30 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9801, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
---

================================================================================

Configuring TLS exceptions with PFS disabled for xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx

---
TLSv1.2 with PFS disabled
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.2";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
2017-03-20 19:27:20.020 nscurl[16582:163070] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)
2017-03-20 19:27:20.021 nscurl[16582:163070] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)
Result : FAIL
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbdf3534c00 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9801, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
---

---
TLSv1.1 with PFS disabled
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.1";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.0 with PFS disabled
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx" =         {
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.0";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================

Configuring TLS exceptions with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed for xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx

---
TLSv1.2 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.2";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
2017-03-20 19:27:20.358 nscurl[16582:163070] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)
2017-03-20 19:27:20.416 nscurl[16582:163070] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)
2017-03-20 19:27:20.471 nscurl[16582:163070] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9801)
2017-03-20 19:27:20.471 nscurl[16582:163070] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801)
Result : FAIL
Error : Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fbdf3530fd0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9801, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
---

---
TLSv1.1 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.1";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

---
TLSv1.0 with PFS disabled and insecure HTTP allowed
ATS Dictionary:
{
    NSExceptionDomains =     {
        "xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxx" =         {
            NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads = true;
            NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion = "TLSv1.0";
            NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy = false;
        };
    };
}
Result : PASS
---

================================================================================
```

Comment: Have you tried `nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose https://www.google.com`, but to your domain instead of google? Also, which cipher suites are supported by the server?

Comment: @Mats, Thanks for your replay. I euecuted the comment in terminal and I posted the result in question.

Comment: Instead of trying all the keys, what @Mats suggested will give you the actual reason. You can do something based on diagnostics results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added following key also in info.plist the issue get resolved.

```
<key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
<false/>
```